# Eclipse error exporting war

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, war

I'm trying to export a Web Project as a WAR file, I get this error:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingC:/Users/jp/Desktop/beta.war
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:150)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.ArchiveSaveFailureException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.FlatComponentArchiver.saveArchive(FlatComponentArchiver.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.export(ComponentExportOperation.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:136)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any ideas about the java.lang.NullPointerException?
It's a project that has a lot of dependencies, but they seem to be fine (at least Eclipse is not complaining)

UPDATE
I tried several approaches, among them: re-installed Eclipse, created the workspace again, fresh project configuration, downloaded the full repository again... nothing seems to work.

As additional information, other web projects can be exported to WAR files without issues.
I read that this may be caused by web.xml misconfiguration, but I couldn't find errors in mine. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem, but it simply dissapeared after some time. Now I'm having it again. If you was able to solve it, please answer your own question. If I'm able to solve it i'll post an answer here too.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not code specific, this issue is eclipse specific. In some cases, if you have added eclipse updates which doesn't have proper license then this issue might arise. I use eclipse Kepler, I had faced same issue, no other solution worked for me, so I simply used another copy eclipse and then I easily exported new war.

P.S.- With older eclipse, I could export other projects, but I had faced this problem with only one project.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a couple of hard-coded paths for some imported libraries.
After moving the project to a different path, it still had the old path referenced. And for some reason I don't understand, Eclipse didn't catch it.